# Equal width + TailTruncation in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I am trying to build a listview with 4 equal width columns.
I am trying HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" for that and it works unless label text is wider than 1/4 of screen width.
Is there a way to trunk the label to fit the 1/4 screen?
The only idea I have is separate fixed-size grids in both the header and each row.
Here's XAML:

```
            <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Members}">
            <ListView.Header>
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Label Text="Experience Level"/>
                    <Label Text="Years of Experience"/>
                    <Label Text="Max Hourly Rate"/>
                    <Label Text="Professional/Consultant"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </ListView.Header>
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Label Text="{Binding ExperienceLevelType.Name}" LineBreakMode="TailTruncation"  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
                            <Label Text="{Binding YearsOfExperience}" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
                            <Label Text="{Binding HourlyRateMax}" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
                            <Button Text="Search" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `Grid`, would recommend using `AbsoluteLayout`.

```
<ListView x:Name="listView" ItemsSource="{Binding Members}">
    <ListView.Header>
        <AbsoluteLayout HeightRequest="50" BackgroundColor="Silver">
            <Label
                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,.25,1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" 
                HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Center"
                LineBreakMode="WordWrap" Text="Experience Level"/>
            <Label
                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds=".325,0,.25,1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" 
                HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center"
                LineBreakMode="WordWrap" Text="Years of Experience"/>
            <Label
                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds=".65,0,.25,1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" 
                HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center"
                LineBreakMode="WordWrap" Text="Max Hourly Rate"/>
            <Label
                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="1,0,.25,1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
                HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Center"
                LineBreakMode="WordWrap" Text="Professional/Consultant"/>
        </AbsoluteLayout>
    </ListView.Header>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <AbsoluteLayout>
                    <Label 
                        AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,.25,1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" 
                        HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Center"
                        LineBreakMode="TailTruncation" Text="{Binding ExperienceLevelType.Name}"/>
                    <Label
                        AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds=".325,0,.25,1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
                        HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center"
                        LineBreakMode="TailTruncation" Text="{Binding YearsOfExperience}" />
                    <Label
                        AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds=".65,0,.25,1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" 
                        HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center"
                        LineBreakMode="TailTruncation" Text="{Binding HourlyRateMax}" />
                    <Button
                        AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="1,0,.25,1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
                        HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Center"
                        Text="Search" />
                </AbsoluteLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```